# node mocha babel how to avoid parsing a specific library?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, webstorm, babeljs

CMy project directory structure is the following :

```
project
   |_ config  ( config .js files)
   |_ coverage ( reporting result files )
   |_ dist ( compiled project for distribution )
   |_ docs ( temporary wip .js files NOT TO BE parsed ! )
   |_ server
       |_helpers ( js files )
       |_models. ( js files )
       |_v1
          |_controllers ( js files)
          |_routes (js files )
          L_tests ( js files )
      |_ all .files ( .env, .git, .yarn, ..etc
      |_index.js
      |_package.json
```

running a test :

```
    "test:v1": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test ./node_modules/.bin/mocha 
    --timeout 15000 --ui bdd --reporter spec --colors 
    --compilers js:babel-core/register server/v1/tests/user.test.js 
    --recursive",
```

I get a parsing error on a .js files which is located in the doc directory
as these files are not to e taken in account in the test, how can I avoid parsing of the docs directory ?
I am using Webstorm 2017 as an IDE...

thanks for feedback

UPDATE

in my package.json file I have :

```
"babel": {
  "presets": [
    "es2015",
    "stage-2"
  ],
  "ignore": "docs/**/*.js", <= also tried ./docs/**/*.js
  "plugins": [
    "add-module-exports"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can configure your Babel to skip a particular file or folder: https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/babelrc/

For example, try adding to your `package.json`:

```
  "babel": {
    "ignore": "docs/**/*.js"
  }
```

**UPD**: looks like this is one of the most requested mochajs features - https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/issues/1577

Try adding `'!docs/**/*.js'` to your test command. Like

```
cross-env NODE_ENV=test ./node_modules/.bin/mocha 
    --timeout 15000 --ui bdd --reporter spec --colors 
    --compilers js:babel-core/register 'server/v1/tests/user.test.js' '!docs/**/*.js' 
    --recursive
```

Comment: thanks Vlad .. I tried it too. ( see UPDATE in my question..  no change..

Comment: @erwin thanks for the clarification, I updated my answer as well

Comment: does not work :  got Warning: Could not find any test files matching pattern: !docs/**/*.js

Comment: GOT IT ... removing the docs subdirectory.. I got an error , requesting an old xxx.route.js file which was in in docs subdirectory . I forgot to remove some importas in the index.js file ! so the --recursive option is doing its job and looking for it upwards...  your comment should be good but the --recirsive option was taking over it...  THNAKS A LOT

Answer (score 0):

The issue comes from the fact that I forgot to remove from my index.route.js some imports from old xxx.route.js located into the docs directory... the --recursive options is getting them and parsing them for compilation...

Found this solution by removing the faulty docs directory and then getting another type of error :  not found !